# Pod to pod communication GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this terraform-kubernetes script [terraform1](https://github.com/kokizzu/terraform1)

so prometheus scraping list of pods, and hitting `/metrics` based on custom resource `Prometheus` and `PodMonitor` rules

it's working fine locally using minikube,

but in GKE, it doesn't work,

podmonitor works normally:

[image: service discovery works]

but scraping failed (this part is green when on local minikube):

[image: scraping targets]

normally when I open the website on using port forwarding (32009 to random localhost port) it works normally 200, no error:

[image: metrics exists using port-forwrding]

does GKE disallow pod to pod communication? seems not since the error is 403 instead of something else, or I need to do something so Prometheus pod that lives on 10.63.1.4 can scrape other pods in the target list (10.63.1.252, 10.63.1.5, 10.63.3.5, 10.63.4.210, 10.63.1.133, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's software issue, the software being deployed have blocking on specific headers, it only allows specific `Host:` header, that's why it's 403 instead of timeout or something else.